# how to prevent my program to open the same window Form twice

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

i am working on a project, i am creating a instance and opening a specific form in my program, like i use following code to open a form:

```
  frm2 cs = new frm2();
  cs.Show();
```

but the problem here is each time i click on the button it just open a new windows and the previous one is also opened, all i want to do here is when i click on button and that window is already open then it simply go to already opened windows except opening the new one.
hope you guys understand my question and will help me doing it.

### EDIT:

i tried this code : the code i wrote in frm2.cs file is:

```
   public partial class frm2 : Form
    {

       private static frm2 _form2 = null; 

        public frm2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static frm2 Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (_form2 == null)
                {
                    _form2 = new frm2();
                }
                return _form2;              
            }
        }
```

and in frmMain.cs file where i code to access the instance and open the project is :

```
private void addProductToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
       frm2.Instance.Show();  

       //frm2 cs = new frm2();
      //cs.Show();
  }
```

it work fine the first time, but when i open the frm2 , close it and then again try to open it the compiler give error at  `frm2.Instance.Show();`   and the error comes is

```
: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'frm2'.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Save the instance of the form opened in a global class variable and then, if this variable is not null just call Show instead of opening againg. Some tips should be followed though

```
public class Form1: Form
{
     private frm2 _currentInstance = null;
     ....

     if(_currentInstance == null)
     {
         _currentInstance = new frm2();
         _currentInstance.FormClosed += instanceHasBeenClosed;
         _currentInstance.Show();
     }
     _currentInstance.BringToFront();

     ....

     private void instanceHasBeenClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
     {
         _currentInstance = null;
     }
}
```

It is important to subscribe to the FormClosed event for the _currentInstance. In this way your Form1 will be notified when your user closes the instance. And you could reset the internal variable to null, so at the subsequent click you could reopen again the instance

There is also the possibility to use the [Application.OpenForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) collection to check if your form is shown

```
frm2 f = Application.OpenForms["NameOfForm2"];
if(f != null)
   f.BringToFront();
else
{
   frm2 f = new frm2();
   f.Show();
}
```

Comment: You may want "BringToFront" not "Show"

Comment: But the first time the Show is needed

Comment: can't we just do it in more simple way?

Comment: It depends on the exact semantics that you want the sub-form to have.  Do you want the sub-form's state to persist if you close it and re-open it, or do you want closing it and re-opening it to reset its state?  If you want the state to persist, you could just instantiate the sub-form once.  If you want the state to reset, this is about as simple as it gets.

Comment: i just want it to show me already opened window simple, dont want to create a lengthy code or classes in here

Comment: Use an else clause to restore the WindowState and call BringToFront().  Let's ignore the OP :)

Comment: Also If you want to follow the singleton pattern you need to subscribe to the FormClosed event (this time inside frm2 code) to set the global variable to null when that instance closes. Otherwise you would use a reference to a memory object that is no more valid. After all, if you don't have any special requirement about the frm2 instance then you could simply use the OpenForms collection

Answer (score 4):

I know you don't want to write that much code but it seems this is the only way to go.

At least, you can separate that code from your forms by writing a generic code.

```
var f = FormManager.Show<Form2>(); //create a new form.
f = FormManager.Show<Form2>(); //show the existing form.
f.Close();
f = FormManager.Show<Form2>(); //create a new form
```

---

```
public static class FormManager
{
    static Dictionary<Type, Form> _Forms = new Dictionary<Type, Form>();

    public static T Show<T>() where T: Form, new()
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        Form f = null;
        if(_Forms.TryGetValue(type,out f))
        {
            f.BringToFront();
        }
        else
        {
            f = new T();
            f.FormClosing += (s, e) => _Forms.Remove(s.GetType());
            _Forms.Add(type, f);
            f.Show();
        }
        return (T)f;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use [`singleton`](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternSingleton.aspx#intent) design pattern to return always the same instance

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private  static Form2  _form2 = null; 
    private Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public static  Form2 Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_form2 == null)
            {
                _form2 = new Form2();  
            }
            return _form2;  

        }
    }


}
```

// use this to call the instance

```
 Form2.Instance.Show();
```

Comment: This is my prefered method to, a few detailed examples [here](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternSingleton.aspx#intent)

Comment: But this requires  repeating the same code for every form. I would write a FormFactory without making any changes to forms.

Comment: yes  that's possible too  but here I  think that the OP need this only  for form2

Comment: After first call `this._form2` will be always `not null`... Need add code to `FormClosing` eventhandler

Comment: When I try, it sais: "Member x.Instance cannot be accessed with an instance reference". 1st example of Jim's comment fixed it. (`X x = X.Instance; x.Show();`)

Answer (score 2):

Singleton pattern may be a way to go - just apply it to windows forms (you can check this link for the description of the singleton pattern in C#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx).

Comment: Well, I linked that article because it contains nice description, shows you several implementations and gives you some pros and cons. It can also be used to solve your problem and you will have a good understanding of singleton pattern if you read it.

Comment: I dont think that article is anywhere near lenghty. But I also dont think he needs a singleton. He just needs to think about his classes and objects. IMHO, the Singleton is way overused.

Answer (score 0):

Check on multiple buttons in that Form is open or not:

```
private bool isOpen(string name)
        {
            IsOpen = false;
            foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms)
            {
                if (f.Text == name)
                {
                    IsOpen = true;
                    f.Focus();
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (IsOpen == false)
            {
                return IsOpen;
            }
            return IsOpen;
        }
```

Call this in the button click to Check the current Form:

```
 if (isOpen("Item Import Master")) ;
            else
            {
                Item_Import_Master obj1 = new Item_Import_Master();
                obj1.Show();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if a form is Disposed before you show it again, otherwise you get Cannot access a disposed object exeption

something like this should work

```
private static AdvancedRDSWindow form2;
private AdvancedRDSWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
public static AdvancedRDSWindow Instance
{
    get
    {
        if (form2 == null || form2.IsDisposed)
        {
            form2 = new AdvancedRDSWindow();
        }
        return form2;
```

and then you can show it with a button for instance

```
private void AdvancedRDS_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AdvancedRDSWindow.Instance.Show(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this code in the button click event**

*If the form is already opened, it will bring the form to front*

```
# Here is my code.. #

foreach (Form form in Application.OpenForms)
{
    if (form.GetType() == typeof(frm2))
    {
        form.Activate();
        return;
    }
}

frm2 frm = new frm2();
frm.Show();
```

Comment: The original question is using `frm2 : Form` not `Menu`, you might want to fix that, or replace the inline type with a method taking a generic.